# Programmatically read and set buffer-wide org-mode property

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How one can programmatically read and set a buffer-wide org-mode property?

I am aware of [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14572/how-do-i-programmatic-add-delete-and-update-org-mode-properties-from-entries), which points to

```
(org-entry-put POM "PWE-1" "47")
```

but it does not seem useful in case of buffer global properties.

#### Details:

If a file has buffer global properties, like,

```
#+PROPERTY: PWE-1 42
#+PROPERTY: Cite "Silmarillon 1984"
#+PROPERTY: my/common-list (1 "two" (1 2 3 5 7))
```

How could one fetch, for example, the buffer-wide property PWE-1, or any other?

How would one set it, ie, write a different value, say

```
#+PROPERTY: PWE-1 2197
```

so that the buffer will *keep the updated value as stored in the file, available at next load*?

Where could I look up similar information in detail? Is there a detailed list of org-mode's API?

Comment: There is [`org-element-parse-buffer`](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html). Maybe, that helps. As far as I remember, you get also the buffer positions of the parsed stuff. So you can replace the text for `PWE-1`. (Don't have time to check right now.)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. That page pointed to http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/org-element-docstrings.html, but it does not seem to list a global #+PROPERTY as a parseable element?

Comment: Just do `(setq p (org-element-parse-buffer))` and you will get `(org-data nil (section (:begin 1 :end 108 :contents-begin 1 :contents-end 107 :post-blank 1 :parent #0) (keyword (:key "PROPERTY" :value "PWE-1 42" :begin 1 :end 22 :post-blank 0 :post-affiliated 1 :parent #1))` at the beginning of `p` if your example text is at the beginning of the current org-buffer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `:PROPERTIES:`, then `:PWE-1: 42`, then `:END:`?

Comment: @mankoff That would be a drawer for the current tree. `#+PROPERTY: PWE-1 42` is also fine. That's global. (See info files.)

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for that, it is a powerful notation. It is not clear to me how to use it to access precisely one given property, and how to set a given property? I know I could resort to regex search and replace, but I was looking for either a standard org API to do it, or perhaps some elisp code I could study?

Comment: Just try `(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'keyword (lambda (el) (when (string-equal (org-element-property :key el) "PROPERTY") (nth 1 el))))`. You should be able to do something with the returned list.

Comment: @tobias instead of providing an answer in a string of comments, perhaps you could provide your answer as an answer ;)

Comment: @tobias I am grateful for your suggestions. I am struggling in digging the code. I was hoping there was a straight API for that, advanced org-mode programming is quite still arcane to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just do a text search for `#+PROPERTY: ...`.

Alternatively, you can use the following functions.
These functions take into account that values can be accumulated via `+` and it is an error if the first `PROPERTY` key has a `+`. (Is that true?)

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun org-global-props-key-re (key)
  "Construct a regular expression matching key and an optional plus and eating the spaces behind.
Test for existence of the plus: (match-beginning 1)"
  (concat "^" (regexp-quote key) "\\(\\+\\)?[[:space:]]+"))

(defun org-global-props (&optional buffer)
  "Get the plists of global org properties of current buffer."
  (with-current-buffer (or buffer (current-buffer))
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'keyword (lambda (el) (when (string-equal (org-element-property :key el) "PROPERTY") (nth 1 el))))))

(defun org-global-prop-value (key)
  "Get global org property KEY of current buffer.
Adding up values for one key is supported."
  (let ((key-re (org-global-props-key-re key))
    (props (org-global-props))
    ret)
    (cl-loop with val for prop in props
         when (string-match key-re (setq val (plist-get prop :value))) do
         (setq
          val (substring val (match-end 0))
          ret (if (match-beginning 1)
              (concat ret " " val)
            val)))
    ret))

(defun org-global-prop-set (key value)
  "Set the value of the first occurence of
#+PROPERTY: KEY
add it at the beginning of file if there is none."
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((key-re (org-global-props-key-re key))
       (prop (cl-find-if (lambda (prop)
                   (string-match key-re (plist-get prop :value)))
                 (org-global-props))))
      (if prop
      (progn
        (assert (null (match-beginning 1)) "First occurence of key %s is followed by +." key)
        (goto-char (plist-get prop :begin))
        (kill-region (point) (plist-get prop :end)))
    (goto-char 1))
      (insert "#+PROPERTY: " key " " value "\n"))))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I am able to fetch and set  a buffer-wide property just by specifying its name, ie `(org-global-prop-value "pwe-1")`, `(org-global-prop-set "pwe-1" "77")`. Your code is quite instructive, I am learning a lot. It should be included in org-mode API, I am sure I am not the only one to find it very useful! Thank you.

Comment: `org-global-prop-value` is quite slow

Comment: This is insanely difficult for such a common need.

Answer (score 3):

`(org-collect-keywords '("PROPERTY"))` could also be helpful, as mentioned in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63102/31740.

The `org-collect-keywords` doc string states:

> Return values for KEYWORDS in current buffer, as an alist.
>
> KEYWORDS is a list of strings.  Return value is a list of
> elements with the pattern:
>
> (NAME . LIST-OF-VALUES)
>
> where NAME is the upcase name of the keyword, and LIST-OF-VALUES
> is a list of non-empty values, as strings, in order of appearance
> in the buffer.

This allows one to *get* the property values, but it does not allow *setting* them. In fact, Org mode does not provide *any* way of setting them, so @Tobias's answer still stands for the setting part: you basically have to edit the file, either by hand or programatically.

Comment: Please summarize the part of the content at that URL that you think answers the question. Otherwise, this risks being deleted as a link-only answer. Thx.

Comment: done as requested

Comment: Thank you. Great answer that does exactly what I wanted, out of the box. It even handles case insensitive matching.