# How to get property values from org file headers

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to get property values from org file headers? For example, I have a file named `something.org` with following content:

```
#+TITLE: Awesome File
#+AUTHOR: My Name
#+XYZ: xyz

/content/
```

How could one get title or `XYZ`? I want to get those values for some buffer-local variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a slight modification of [the answer to another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/programmatically-read-and-set-buffer-wide-org-mode-property).
After trying the full stuff in some org-file you can put `https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/programmatically-read-and-set-buffer-wide-org-mode-property` into your init file and just use `org-global-props` in your org-file.

```el
#+TITLE: Awesome File
#+AUTHOR: My Name
#+XYZ: xyz

  /content/
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;; Definition of `org-global-props' that could go into your init file:
(defun org-global-props (&optional property buffer)
  "Get the plists of global org properties of current buffer."
  (unless property (setq property "PROPERTY"))
  (with-current-buffer (or buffer (current-buffer))
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'keyword (lambda (el) (when (string-match property (org-element-property :key el)) el)))))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Stuff for your org-file:
(mapcar (lambda (prop)
      (list (org-element-property :key prop)
        (org-element-property :value prop)))
    (org-global-props "\\(AUTHOR\\|TITLE\\|XYZ\\)"))
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  | TITLE  | Awesome File |
  | AUTHOR | My Name      |
  | XYZ    | xyz          |
```

In order to get value of first property with `key` you can use following function.

```
(defun org-global-prop-value (key)
  "Get global org property KEY of current buffer."
  (org-element-property :value (car (org-global-props key))))
```

For example, `(org-global-prop-value "author")` returns `My Name`. Keep in mind, that `key` respects case sensitivity rules for search.

Comment: Nice, pretty almost what I wanted. Will do some modification and it would be perfect. BTW, thanks for the link. I saw that question, but didn't see that it's useful for my case as well :-P

Comment: But anyway, `(org-element-property :value (car (org-global-props "AUTHOR")))` is fine enough. Thanks again.

Comment: @d12frosted Yes, ... it is more like getting you on the right track.

Comment: @d12frosted Please post what was the perfect answer for you. You might not be the only one who it is perfect for.

Answer (score 4):

`org-collect-keywords` will do this for you.

In your document, `(org-collect-keywords '("TITLE" "XYZ"))` will return `(("TITLE" "Awesome File") ("XYZ" "xyz"))`.